# Selecting Random record in a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have got a datagrid view in my windows form project that is is filled up with data.. I have also a button (nextButton) that is clicked to go through these records. Is there a way I can select a random record from the datagrid view whenever the next button is clicked.

This is my code that fills up the datagridview.

```
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
        SqlCommand db = new SqlCommand("select * from TblEmp where Emp_Title = 'Mr'", conn);
        SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
        dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(db);
        dataset = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataset, "TblEmp");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables["TblEmp"];
```

And here is the code for the nextButoon that goes through records

```
void NextRecord()
{
    if ( RecordCounter; dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count -1)
    {
        RecordCounter++;
        TxtDisplayQuestion.Text = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[ RecordCounter][Emp_Title].ToString();
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick. To avoid selecting the same row twice, the method remembers the last selected row and tries to find a new random row if the same row is selected a second time.

```
private Random rnd = new Random();
private int lastSelectedIndex = -1;

void RandomRecord()
{
    int noRows = dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    int index = rnd.Next(noRows);

    while(index == lastSelectedIndex && noRows > 1) {
        index = rnd.Next(noRows);
    }

    lastSelectedIndex = index;

    TxtDisplayQuestion.Text = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[index][Emp_Title].ToString();
}
```

Comment: hmmm, for some reason sometimes a record is selected twice with the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume this is `WinForms` due to the naming, but correct me if I'm wrong.

You could define a new instance of the `Random` class at the top of the form:

```
var r = new Random(Environment.TickCount);
```

Then access a random row from the grid using:

```
var randomGridRow = dataGridView.Rows[r.Next(0, dataGridView.RowCount)];
```

Or from the `DataTable` itself:

```
var randomTableRow = dt.Rows[r.Next(0, dt.Rows.Count)];
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
void NextRecord()
{
    var rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    var randomNumber = rnd.Next(dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1);
    TxtDisplayQuestion.Text = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[randomNumber][Emp_Title].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you .. Is there a way I can avoid this from selecting the same record twice??

Comment: Adding the record to a list of viewed records, or maybe adding a bool to the class the record consists of.